# Удалить из сообщения все слова, содержащий данный символ (без учёта регистра). На языке C#

Tags: c#, символы, удаление

Вот код который я написал, он удаляет только один символ в то время как мне нужно удалить целое слово содержащий данный символ.

```
        Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
        StringBuilder m = new StringBuilder(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите символ из-за которого будет удаляться слово: ");
        char q = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
        {
            if(q == m[i])
            {
                m.Replace(m[i],' ');
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Изменённая строка: " + m);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var symbolToDelete = "o".ToLower();

var words = someString.Split(' ')
                      .Where( a => !a.ToLower().Contains(symbolToDelete ) );

var res = String.Join(" ", words);
```

Comment: Плохой ответ: 1) это не Java, `Split(' ')` 2) `ToLower()` зачем? 3) лучше использовать контекст кода из вопроса 4) `->` должно быть `=>` 5) не `Select`, а `Where`.

Comment: @aepot 1 - я на джаве и не пишу... я сейчас со свифтом работаю. Понятия не имею что там на джаве, а на шарпе пишу по памяти не проверяя т.к. нету виндового компа под рукой 2. - мне показалось что лучше это делать вне зависимости от регистра символа. Если это не подойдет - проапдейтить код просто 3. Думаю код не сильно поменяется если использовать стринг билдер вместо стринга. 4 и 5. а за эти уточнения спасибо

Comment: https://sharplab.io

Comment: сохранил) ______

Comment: этот лучше ИМХО https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
var newList = m.ToString()
           .Split(' ')
           .ToList()
           .RemoveAll(x => x.IndexOf(q) > -1);
var finalStr = string.Join(' ', newList);
```

Comment: Операция удаления из списка дороже чем отфильтровывания существующего списка.  Но учитывая что задача несерьезная, можно спокойно забить болт. Тем более что у тебя код читабельнее моего. С меня плюс за иной подход на ЛИНКе.

Comment: Единственное что - регистрозависимый ответ, а автор просил в заголовке регистронезависимый

Comment: Просто добавил как альтернативный вариант. На счет "дороже", это наверное заметно когда несколько тысяч слов. Но тогда это задача будет несколько странной. По поводу регистра, можно сделать ToUpper() или ToLower().